# Showing issue but hide code with Gitlab

Tags: permissions, gitlab

I have a self hosted gitlab repository. I don't want to publish the code, but I would love to use the awesome ticketing system for my beta tester.

Is is possible to have a profile that can create/comment issue but has no right to see the source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 2021 update:

The tables seems to have evolved a lot during the last months, you can browse it here : https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/blob/master/doc/user/permissions.md

---

#### Original post:

Well it seems that `Guest` is what you're looking for (shamelessly stolen from [Gitlab Permissions.md file](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/user/permissions.md)):

```
| Action                                | Guest   | Reporter   | Developer   | Master   | Owner  |
|---------------------------------------|---------|------------|-------------|----------|--------|
| Create new issue                      | ✓ [^1]  | ✓          | ✓           | ✓        | ✓      |
| Create confidential issue             | ✓ [^1]  | ✓          | ✓           | ✓        | ✓      |
| View confidential issues              | (✓) [^2] | ✓          | ✓           | ✓        | ✓      |
| Leave comments                        | ✓ [^1]  | ✓          | ✓           | ✓        | ✓      |
| See a list of jobs                    | ✓ [^3]  | ✓          | ✓           | ✓        | ✓      |
| See a job   log                       | ✓ [^3]  | ✓          | ✓           | ✓        | ✓      |
| Download and browse job artifacts     | ✓ [^3]  | ✓          | ✓           | ✓        | ✓      |
| View wiki pages                       | ✓ [^1]  | ✓          | ✓           | ✓        | ✓      |
| Pull project code                     | [^1]    | ✓          | ✓           | ✓        | ✓      |
| Download project                      | [^1]    | ✓          | ✓           | ✓        | ✓      |
| Create code snippets                  |         | ✓          | ✓           | ✓        | ✓      |
| Manage issue tracker                  |         | ✓          | ✓           | ✓        | ✓      |
| Manage labels                         |         | ✓          | ✓           | ✓        | ✓      |
| See a commit status                   |         | ✓          | ✓           | ✓        | ✓      |
| See a container registry              |         | ✓          | ✓           | ✓        | ✓      |
| See environments                      |         | ✓          | ✓           | ✓        | ✓      |
| Create new environments               |         |            | ✓           | ✓        | ✓      |
| Use environment terminals             |         |            |             | ✓        | ✓      |
| Stop environments                     |         |            | ✓           | ✓        | ✓      |
| See a list of merge requests          |         | ✓          | ✓           | ✓        | ✓      |
| Manage/Accept merge requests          |         |            | ✓           | ✓        | ✓      |
| Create new merge request              |         |            | ✓           | ✓        | ✓      |
| Create new branches                   |         |            | ✓           | ✓        | ✓      |
| Push to non-protected branches        |         |            | ✓           | ✓        | ✓      |
| Force push to non-protected branches  |         |            | ✓           | ✓        | ✓      |
| Remove non-protected branches         |         |            | ✓           | ✓        | ✓      |
| Add tags                              |         |            | ✓           | ✓        | ✓      |
| Write a wiki                          |         |            | ✓           | ✓        | ✓      |
| Cancel and retry jobs                 |         |            | ✓           | ✓        | ✓      |
| Create or update commit status        |         |            | ✓           | ✓        | ✓      |
| Update a container registry           |         |            | ✓           | ✓        | ✓      |
| Remove a container registry image     |         |            | ✓           | ✓        | ✓      |
| Create new milestones                 |         |            |             | ✓        | ✓      |
| Add new team members                  |         |            |             | ✓        | ✓      |
| Push to protected branches            |         |            |             | ✓        | ✓      |
| Enable/disable branch protection      |         |            |             | ✓        | ✓      |
| Turn on/off protected branch push for devs|         |            |             | ✓        | ✓      |
| Enable/disable tag protections        |         |            |             | ✓        | ✓      |
| Rewrite/remove Git tags               |         |            |             | ✓        | ✓      |
| Edit project                          |         |            |             | ✓        | ✓      |
| Add deploy keys to project            |         |            |             | ✓        | ✓      |
| Configure project hooks               |         |            |             | ✓        | ✓      |
| Manage runners                        |         |            |             | ✓        | ✓      |
| Manage job triggers                   |         |            |             | ✓        | ✓      |
| Manage variables                      |         |            |             | ✓        | ✓      |
| Manage pages                          |         |            |             | ✓        | ✓      |
| Manage pages domains and certificates |         |            |             | ✓        | ✓      |
| Switch visibility level               |         |            |             |          | ✓      |
| Transfer project to another namespace |         |            |             |          | ✓      |
| Remove project                        |         |            |             |          | ✓      |
| Force push to protected branches [^4] |         |            |             |          |        |
| Remove protected branches [^4]        |         |            |             |          |        |
| Remove pages                          |         |            |             |          | ✓      |

[^1]: If **Allow guest to access builds** is enabled in CI settings
[^2]: Not allowed for Guest, Reporter, Developer, Master, or Owner
```

You can also take a look at [Keeping your code protected](https://about.gitlab.com/2014/11/26/keeping-your-code-protected/) which states:

> In our experience, this covers almost all cases and can be fitted to any organisation easily.
>
> - Guest - **No access to code**
> - Reporter - Read the repository
> - Developer - Read/Write to the repository
> - Master - Read/Write to the repository + partial administrative capabilities
> - Owner - Read/Write to the repository + full administrative capabilities

Comment: Be advised that since they posted "Keeping your code protected" article, a Reporter role got an ability to manage (i.e. admin) issues and labels, so the article kind of contradicts the table

 (https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/908)

Comment: The table clearly shows that Guests have read-access to the code.

Comment: You are using the wrong table in the answer. I just want to clarify on behalf of users coming from search engines - please check the link in the answer to get the most up-to-date knowledge about this (https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/user/permissions.md) . In this case, if the project is private - the guest user does not have access to code, but have access to issues. If the project is public or internal, the guest user can see the code as well.